# Return columns where values not false

Tags: pandas

I want to conditionally return only columns where values are not `False`

**Code**

```
cols = ['Val', 'weekly_low', 'weekly_high','monthly_low']
values = [1,True,False,False]
df = pd.DataFrame(values).T
df.columns = cols
```

**Example DataFrame**

```
    Val weekly_low  weekly_high monthly_low
0    1  True        False       False
```

I can filter this single row as follows to remove `False`:

```
df[list(df.apply(lambda x: df.columns[x != False].values, axis=1)[0])]
```

Which return **desired output**:

```
    Val weekly_low
0   1   True
```

Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: Does your dataframe always only have 1 row? If there are several, do you need to remove any columns containing at least 1 `False` ? Or containing only `False`?

Comment: It will have multiple rows but not more than say 20.  My plan is to loop through the df, return columns where values are not false for each individual row and then send each individual row to the database.  I appreciate multiple rows is a different challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to compare against `False`, which you can then generalize to all rows or to any row (which for a 1 row dataframe is the same) (or even a specific row with `[0]` as you’re doing currently):

```
>>> df.eq(False)
     Val  weekly_low  weekly_high  monthly_low
0  False       False         True         True
>>> df.eq(False).any()
Val            False
weekly_low     False
weekly_high     True
monthly_low     True
dtype: bool
```

Note that you can also invert the boolean notations, instead of checking any values equal to `False`, you can check all values are non-`False`:

```
>>> df.ne(False).all()
Val             True
weekly_low      True
weekly_high    False
monthly_low    False
dtype: bool
```

From there you could select columns that return True in this series:

```
>>> df.columns[df.ne(False).all()]
Index(['Val', 'weekly_low'], dtype='object')
>>> df[df.columns[df.ne(False).all()]]
   Val  weekly_low
0    1        True
```

Or pass the boolean series directly to `.loc[]`:

```
>>> df.loc[:, df.ne(False).all()]
   Val  weekly_low
0    1        True
```

Finally you might find that `False` is equal to anything falsey, e.g. int or float `0`. If you want to change that you need to check the types. This could be done at a column level:

```
>>> df.dtypes
Val            int64
weekly_low      bool
weekly_high     bool
monthly_low     bool
dtype: object
>>> df.eq(False).any() & df.dtypes.eq(bool)
Val            False
weekly_low     False
weekly_high     True
monthly_low     True
dtype: bool
```

Or at the value level if you have mixed-type columns:

```
>>> df.applymap(type)
             Val      weekly_low     weekly_high     monthly_low
0  <class 'int'>  <class 'bool'>  <class 'bool'>  <class 'bool'>
>>> (df.eq(False) & df.applymap(type).eq(bool)).any()
Val            False
weekly_low     False
weekly_high     True
monthly_low     True
dtype: bool
```

---

With additional information, here’s how I would do it iterating on rows:

```
for idx, ser in df.iterrows():
    ser[ser != False] # Series of non-False in this row
    ser[ser != False].columns # Column names of non-False in this row
    ser[ser != False].columns.to_list() # Same, as list
```